# « Je ne suis plus jeune jeune » ?

Tags: adjectifs, québec, registre-familier, régionalismes, superlatifs

> Je ne suis plus *jeune jeune*. [...bien/très jeune.]

Il y a une répétition de l'adjectif qui gagne en intensité. Je semble connaître le même procédé dans un registre familier avec des adjectifs comme *beau/belle, bon, grand, gros, petit* etc.

- Est-ce une redondance ou une locution distincte de ses éléments,
  est-elle plus figée qu'avec d'autres adjectifs, analyse-t-on le
  premier élément comme l'adverbe *très*, à part le registre y a-t-il
  une nuance ?
- Est-ce un emploi courant des adjectifs ailleurs qu'au Québec ; est-ce
  un régionalisme ou un procédé typique en français (former un
  superlatif avec des adjectifs ?) ; en connaît-on un exemple courant dans son sociolecte ?

Answer (score 4):

Ce procédé, la *réduplication* pour les linguistes, n'est pas spécifique au français québecois, ni au français tout court, il est commun à toutes les langues du monde.

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9duplication) **B. - 2.** LINGUISTIQUE, RHÉTORIQUE Redoublement d'un mot ou d'un élément. *Les mots latins jamjam et quisquis sont des réduplications respectivement de jam et de quis* (Ling.1972). *En particulier Réduplication (...) s'applique notamment au type de répétition expressive qu'on trouve dans: Il n'est pas joli joli. Je le trouve un peu fou fou, etc.* (Colin 1971).

La valeur est à peu près toujours une insistance. Voici quelques exemples courants :

> Affreux, affreux, affreux !
> [Elles sont toutes belles, belles, belles comme le jour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfhu5GJq5BQ)
> Le chien chien à sa mémère
> C'est pas joli joli...
> Écoute, écoute !
> Non non !
> Il est pas sage sage...
> Si si si !
> Tiens tiens...

Un exemple bien connu en italien :

> *[Piano piano](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/pian_piano)*

En espagnol :

> *[Deprisa, deprisa](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivre_vite_!)*

Comment: On la retrouve souvent dans les onomatopées aussi, comme "piou-piou" ou "cui-cui". Les japonais adorent ce genre de construction et en possèdent un nombre phénoménal.

Comment: @Simon Pour le japonais, je ne savais pas mais les onomatopées, c'est vrai ! Ouah ouah, teuf-teuf, bling bling...

Comment: Merci ! D'accord, macro j'avais pas anticipé, mais qu'en est-il de micro, est-ce que je vais généralement entendre _jeune jeune_ en France par exemple, cette combinaison précise d'adjectifs ? Quelle combinaison de deux adjectifs est bien courante en France ?

Comment: @λyoyed'oncques  — C'est une forme de litote pour dire son contraire « je suis vieux » et même « plus que vieux » par rapport à la notion de vieillesse en cours dans le dialogue qui prend en compte l'age physiologique et l'age calendaire. C'est souvent usité dans ce sens : « Ce/cela/il/… n'est pas loin loin » (sous-entendu : mais quand même il faut y aller), *loin loin* pourrait être remplacé par *bien loin*.

Comment: On dit aussi chez nous très couramment *il est plus jeune jeune*. C'est souvent dans des phrases à polarité négative *il est pas vieux vieux*, *la maison est pas grande grande* mais sans la négation, on a le très courant *ça s'est passé moyen moyen*.

Comment: Vous voyez ici je pensais vraiment que c'était un truc bien régional. Pourquoi, je sais pas. Ouais dans mon exemple j'ai mis la particule _ne_ par correction ou autrement, mais on s'entend donc aussi probablement sur le fait que souvent on pourrait ne pas la retrouver. Dans mon contexte d'emploi le plus usuel on aurait encore plus de réduction (yé pu) donc il n'y a pas de place pour la particule dans un tel cas.